# Pass from table editable from php content editable table to javascript method

Tags: javascript, php

Hello im trying to pass the data from a chosen content editable of my looped data table from my php.

But the problem is after i unfocus on my content editable, there is an error saying Uncaught Syntaxerror: Invalid or unexpected token. i dont know how to properly pass or maybe what could the error be as the browser debugger show me that i have passed the variables properly but it says the error.

Anybody knows why?

jscript

```
function edit_first(editableObj,column,std_lrn){
$(".1stperiod").on('blur' ,function (e){ 
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({  
    url:"include/edit.php",
    type:'post',
    data:'column='+column+'&gradedit='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&std_lrn='+std_lrn, 
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
        });
    });
}
```

getgrades.php

```
  $output .= '
    <tr>
      <td>'.$scount.'</td>  
      <td>'.$row["std_fullname"].'</td>  
      <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="edit_first(this,'.$fp.','.$row["std_lrn"].')">'.$row["1stperiod"].'</td>
    ';
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: can you try passing static data like, 'column=column&gradedit=testdata&std_lrn=std_lrn' and still facing error ? and as you calling the function with js, there is no need to bind it with jquery

Comment: Yeah i have tried it but still to no avail. i kinda miss something around javascript code passing multiple parameters from my table as  the debugger shows that i have passed the data through.